# Could not find method annotationProcessor() for arguments

Tags: gradle, travis-ci, lombok

Following is my **build.gradle** file. My project compiles locally (IntelliJ-IDEA is my IDE), but when I push it to GitHub, the **travis-ci** build fails. My gradle version is gradle-5.2.

```
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
version = "1.0"

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
  annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2'
  compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2'
  testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2'
  testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2'
}
```

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file '/home/travis/build/XXX/PROJECT/build.gradle' line: 33
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'PROJECT'.
>
> > Could not find method annotationProcessor() for arguments [org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2] on object of type
> > org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

The `annotationProcessor` in **build.gradle** seems not to be parsed, I'm not sure what the underlying issue is. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: this means you are using an older version of Gradle on your Travis-ci :  the `annotationProcessor` configuration is available since version 4.x (not sure exactly which version), so if you use older version of Gradle you'll get this error.  You should definitely use the Wrapper (see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html)  to avoid such issue

Comment: This `annotationProcessor` is available from Gradle 4.6 (see https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/release-notes.html#convenient-declaration-of-annotation-processor-dependencies )  I guess you have a version < 4.6 on your travis-ci

Comment: @M.Ricciuti Wow~Thank you!!! I have solved my problem after read your word.I used the Wrapper,but I used the `gradle` command too.After I changed it to `./gradlew XXX`,everything works fine.Thanks again :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As @M.Ricciuti said, the `annotationProcessor` is available from gradle versions **4.6** and later. So what we should do is just confirm that gradle's version >= 4.6. We'd be better off using the [**Wrapper**](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html).Thanks, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

A ery easy way to update the gradle version of your project in intellij is to go to inside your project, gradle, wrapper, gradle-wrapper.properties and update the version in the line below:
disributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-bin.zip